# How to use Rules to disable access to selected fields while editing an existing node?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, users

Based on couple of features I require to restrict/disable access to certain field based on other fields while editing the node.

The problem is that in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, there's no "While editing an existing node" event.

What I want is to set an action for the user while editing the node.

Comment: why you don't try it programmatically?

Comment: I'm not a programmer :(

Comment: don't worry "dadash" ;) tell me exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Well I'm working on a workflow system for managing an article submission contest, I need to disable the access to a file field and enable access to another file field after a certain state transition of workflow. So this is basically what I need: If the current state of node is "approved", then disable access to field "summary_article" for instance. thanks "dadash"

Comment: and since you are going to do my job, take a look at here:
http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/workflow/workflow.module/function/workflow_node_current_state/7

Comment: I am busy at this time and minute later I should leave her, but I hope tommarrow can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I kinda managed to do it with a workaround, but it's buggy, so whenever you have the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there is no such event like "While editing an existing node". Probably because an event is something that takes like a fraction of a second, while editing may take minutes (hopefully not hours!).

However, you might get it to work by implementing an "**edit-in-progress**" (= EIP) feature using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, combined with using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Similar to what I described in my answer to "[Can the Flag module be used to lock content while editing to prevent concurrent edits?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179108/how-do-i-lock-content-while-editing-to-prevent-concurrent-edits/179390#179390)" (BTW, that question is a variation of yours, I don't think it's a duplicate though ...).

After you'd have such EIP-flag available, it should be straight forward to use it in appropriate Rules to "*restrict/disable access to certain fields*" (eg based on a data comparison to validate selected field values (using their before and after save values).