# Content Lock on Entityform nodes?

Tags: 7, entities

In Drupal 7, it appears that the [Content Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_lock) module (which prevents concurrent editing of nodes) is not able to work its magic on [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform)-based nodes. Is there a workaround? Something similar with Entityform capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

You might get it to work by implementing an "**edit-in-progress**" (= EIP) feature using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, combined with using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Similar to what I described within "Option 1" in my answer to "[Can the Flag module be used to lock content while editing to prevent concurrent edits?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179108/how-do-i-lock-content-while-editing-to-prevent-concurrent-edits/179390#179390)" (BTW, that question is a variation of yours, not a duplicate though ...).

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Investigating...